# Sqoop Export from Hive table - specifying Delimiters

Tags: xml, hive, export, sqoop

I have a hive table thats Gzip compresed.

**Table Creation**

```
CREATE TABLE table_text (id int, xml string)
PARTITIONED BY (year string, month string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES ('textinputformat.record.delimiter'='#');
```

The xml column has xmls data which is pretty printed. Thats why different line delimiter is chosen.

**Data Load from another table**

```
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;

INSERT OVERWRITE table table_text partition(year=2016,month=2)
select id, decompress(xml) from table_avro;
```

**Validating the load**

```
Select count(*) from table_text;
```

This gives one record, which is fine as the source table table_avro also has one record.

**Sqoop export**

I want to export this gzip compressed data from this hive table to mysql table.

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --username hive --password hive --table  mysql_table_export --hcatalog-table table_text --input-fields-terminated-by '|' --input-lines-terminated-by '#'
```

This exports 14000 odd rows to the mysql table. In fact the xml has 14000 odd lines.

How do i specify the input data line and field separators so that the data is read correctly and exported correctly? Should the output delimiters also need to be specified?

**Updated With sample:**

*table_text - This is just a sample as i cannot paste the actual, but it looks like. The XML spans across lines.*

```
1000|<parent><child>sample
 </child></parent>
```

Comment: Can you please sample data in table table_text and table_avro

Comment: @vinayak I have updated with the sample. I don't think Avro sample data is required as the copy from avro to text is fine. Now its the question of exporting this to Mysql as one single row.